# Facing error as "'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation" while calling rest API in typescript

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript

I am using TypeScript. I am trying to call rest API in a ViewModel like below.

```
export class TestListViewModel {

  public personItems: KnockoutObservableArray<Person>;

  constructor() {
        this.personItems = ko.observableArray([]);

        $.get("https://somerestapi/api/TestLists", 
             function (data: any) {
                 for (var index in data) {
                  this.personItems.push(data[index]);
             } 
        });

  } //end of constructor

} //end of class
```

In line this.personItems.push(data[index]), at "this", I am getting compile error  as **'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation**

Here i want access my Viewmodel variables in call back function.

Please help me how can i do this.

Comment: Try this: `function (data: any) { // your existing code...}.bind(this)`. Or you can use an arrow function

Comment: I am getting the same error if i do $.get("https://somerestapi/api/TestLists", function (data: any) {
            for (var index in data) {
                this.personItems.push(data[index]);
            }
        }.bind(this));

Comment: If i do $.get("https://deleteuserrestapi.azurewebsites.net/api/TestLists", data => {
            for (var index in data) {
                this.personItems.push(data[index]);
            }
        }); I am getting error at "data =>" as "parameter 'data' implicitly has an 'any' type"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue by using below code.

```
$.get("https://somerestapi/api/TestLists", 
             (data: any) => {
                 for (var index in data) {
                    this.personItems.push(data[index]);
                 }
});
```